# D3 Line Graph Example - Having problems with dates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have taken a D3 Line Graph example and changed it slightly to run using local data. I have commented out the data.tsv() and replaced it with a data.forEach() on the var data array, which should accomplish the same thing.

I am trying this example, because I have been having trouble with a line graph and dates. I end up with lot's of NaN in the line's, which then won't draw.

My current version simply and erroneously draws a vertical line at x=0 (over the axis). Here's the SVG path:

```
<path class="line" 
d="M0,450
L0,307.85928143712596
L0,72.7544910179639
L0,0
L0,8.083832335329655
L0,30.314371257485206"></path>
```

I don't know what I am getting wrong. I simply want to graph the data, the 5 points in the data array. I realize I probably have a syntax error (that will cause a head slap when it's pointed out) but more to the point, I can tell I don't understand what D3 wants from time-based data. What type does D3 need for date data, what does time.format.parse() do compared to the javascript date parser? Why use one and not the other? When do I get NaN returns and 0's?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>LGTest</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x.axis path {
        display: none;
    }

    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var data = [
        { date: "24-Apr-07", close: 93.24 },
        { date: "25-Apr-07", close: 95.35 },
        { date: "26-Apr-07", close: 98.84 },
        { date: "27-Apr-07", close: 99.92 },
        { date: "30-Apr-07", close: 99.80 },
        { date: "1-May-07", close: 99.47 }
    ];
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%e-%b-%y");

data.forEach(function (d) { d = type(d) });


var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
//  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
//});

  function type(d) {
      d.date = formatDate.parse(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}

</script>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help, advice, remonstrations, etc.

Comment: I made it a fiddle, what's the problem here? https://jsfiddle.net/xcn35ycm/5/

Comment: Wow. That's a brilliant idea to do it on jsfiddle  - it works there, which is a different result than on my machine! I will update the d3 library I'm using to see if that affects it.

Comment: I will make it an answer so we can update it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it a fiddle. It seems to be working fine, what's the problem here?

I used these data:

```
var data = [
        { date: "24-Apr-07", close: 93.24 },
        { date: "25-Apr-07", close: 95.35 },
        { date: "26-Apr-07", close: 98.84 },
        { date: "27-Apr-07", close: 99.92 },
        { date: "30-Apr-07", close: 99.80 },
        { date: "1-May-07", close: 99.47 }
    ];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xcn35ycm/5/

Comment: So I removed the styles from the code I had, since that was the only real difference between my example and the jsFiddle. Once I did that, It worked. So, it's not necessarily that I don't understand dates, I don't understand the effects of styles and CSS on d3 renderings.

That's important for me to know, so thanks for the lesson!

Comment: jsfiddle is an awesome debugging tool for these kind of stuff. Glad I could help